# Regex matching a forward and backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

In my requirement i have to restrict `\` or `/`.

My text is like below:

```
Need to get good command on \ regex
```

I need to search is there `\` or `/` in above text. If it is available return *true*, if not, return *false*, like `test` method.

Is there any regex that identifies these two in a JavaScript string.

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output as well to make the question easier to understand?

Comment: *"Is there any regex"* - There is more than one way to do this. Is the idea to allow nothing but \ and /, or to allow everything except \ and /?

Comment: My text is like below "Need to get good command on \ regex" .I need to search is there '\' or '/' in above text if it is available return true if not return false  like test method

Comment: It's allow every thing except / and \

Comment: It is a really simple task. `/[\/\\]/.test(s)`

Comment: Sorry by mistakenly i said you / and \ but it is / or \

Comment: As @Yathi suggested, it would be more appropriate if you provide an example of exactly what you need in your question. It will avoid unnecessary efforts from others and you will get a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: If my text is like  "Hello thank you for / your supporting". here i need to test is there / or \.here i found '/' and  give an alert as don't enter / or \.   If my text is like " Hello thank you for \ your supporting " . here '\' is exist then  give an alert  don't enter / or \  and last one  if user enter both means if my text is "  Hello thank / you for \ your supporting  ".and here i found '/' and '\' i need to give an alert don't enter / or \.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\/\\]` that matches either `\` *or* `/`:

```js
var s = "Need to get good command on \\ regex";
if (/[\/\\]/.test(s)) {
 console.log("Text contains a forward or backslash!");
} else {
  console.log("Valid text.");
}
```

Comment: it's not working for this text "Need to get good command on \ regex"

Comment: It is exactly the *text* in my snippet and you see it is working. The *string literal* `"\ "` does not contain a literal backslash, you can see it [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmqj42fL/).